# Add custom auto increment value

Tags: mysql, sql

Am trying to create a MySQL  that tells

> auto_increment

Where and how to start incrementing. Each time I run the code, it always tells me I have error near

> auto.

Each time I removed the "=", it always work.

This is the code

```
CREATE TABLE staff(
id into(11) not null primary key auto_increment=001,
Names varchar(109) not null
);
```

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

First create table like below:

> CREATE TABLE staff( id into(11) not null primary key
> auto_increment, Names varchar(109) not null );

then alter to customized auto increment.

> ALTER TABLE staff AUTO_INCREMENT=001;

Answer (score 0):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE staff(
id int not null primary key auto_increment,
Names varchar(255) not null
)auto_increment=001;
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: @ROHIT KHURANA hope your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The default auto-increment value is an option on the *table* not on the *column* (perhaps counterintuitively, but a table is only allowed to have one such column).

The syntax looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
    id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    Names varchar(109) not null
) auto_increment = 10;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c2adbf9fe9b99b2635aa0bc45a6935d2) is a db<>fiddle.